# Android Loader Implementation for Contacts Retrieval

Tags: android, android-loader

I am practicing Loader's implementation. I have a listview where I want to show the data received from loader. I extended CursorAdapter class as I wanted to implement a custom ListView. Did as it is there on the Loader Documentation page but unfortunately the loader is not returning any data. I debugged the code and found that everything worked fine. only the data isn't showing up on the view. Here is my onCreateLoader method where I have implemented Contacts retrieval code:

```
static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
    };

    @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

            Log.d("DANN", "In onCreateLoader");
            Uri baseUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI;

            String select = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                    + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
                return new CursorLoader(this, baseUri,CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION,
                        select,null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        }
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        Log.d("DANN","in onLoadFinished");
        contactsListAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        Log.d("DANN","In onLoaderReset");
        contactsListAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
```

I copied the selection query from documentation's page. Everything seems to work but my Cursor adapater is not showing any data.

Comment: Are you initializing the loader anywhere?

Comment: Yes. In the same activity where I'm implementing these LoaderCallbacks. 
`getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);`